# Трансляция видео в реальном времени с записью

Tags: c++, online-video, .webm

Задача состоит в том, чтобы передавать потоковое видео на сервер, который будет эти потоки писать на жёсткий диск и параллельно, по запросу, отдавать в браузер стрим в реальном времени. На подобие того, как работает плеер в ютубе - можно или смотреть то, что идёт сейчас, или отмотать назад.

Разобрался с vpx-кодировщиком, в качестве теста освоил запись vp8-пакетов с ivf заголовками (MPC-HC воспроизводит корректно), но, если я правильно понял, в webm пакетах используются другие заголовки, описания которых в [официальной спецификации](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) я что-то не нашёл. Webm выбрал потому, что его изначально понимают и Firefox и Chrome/Chromium.

**Как реализовать стрим, получая от vpx-энкодера в `char * buffer` сырые пакеты vp8?** Какие технологии, заголовки использовать, чтобы и записать можно было, и смотреть в реальном времени? Мне нужно понимать что передавать на сервер, и как это там обрабатывать, чтобы конечный контент был понятен и браузеру, и системному проигрывателю (сервер собственной разработки).

*PS: интересует именно низкоуровневая реализация, а не gstreamer-ы, ffmpeg-и и всё то прочее, что не известно как внутри устроенно.*

Спасибо

Comment: `.webm` основан на формате `matroska` ака `.mkv`